# Can not load lbpcascade_profile.xml

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to load lbpcascade_profileface.xml.

```
CascadeClassifier cad;
cad.load("C:/opencv/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml");
```

Following error shows up:

```
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (C:/opencv/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.x
ml(1): Comments are not allowed here) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\ope
ncv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 1818
```

What to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay found the solution for working it. I had to delete the comments at top of the xml file. Now it works. But don't know why they had added comments that could not be parsed.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and it appears the comment was just misplaced. If you want to preserve the comment, just move this line above the comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```